# Mac OSX Terminal not Recognizing installed CLI Tool

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to literally download and run the ElectronNet demo ([found here](https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos)).  I install the CLI tool, which appears to be accomplished successfully, but when I try to use the tool, terminal does not recognize it.  Shown below:

```
% dotnet tool install electronnet.cli -g
Tool 'electronnet.cli' is already installed.

%electronize start
zsh: command not found: electronize
```

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's something with your path&zsh,
if you try:

```
~/.dotnet/tools/electronize start
```

is that work for you?

If so, you can fix your path by editing ~/.zshrc, add this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet/bin"
```

and source the file by running: "`. ~/.zshrc`"